# Explain the following code snippet?

Tags: c, printf

```
int main()
{   
    int a, b, c;
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = printf("%d", a) + ++b;
    printf("\n%d", c);
}
```

The output of the above program is 23 it seems but i dont know how it is obtained. Can anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 4):

`printf` has a return value, which is the total number of characters it prints.

The statement `printf("%d",a)` will print `10`, which means the return value of `printf` here is `2`.

The rest is easy:

```
c=printf("%d",a)+ ++b;
```

`c` will have a value of `2 + 20 + 1`, which is `23`.

Comment: Excellent explanation. It's also worth pointing out that b is 21 at the end of this function. It got incremented on this line: `c=printf("%d",a)+ ++b;`

Comment: @user814064 Right, that's the side effect. Your answer is correct but it seems that you have deleted it.

Comment: You were first by a few seconds -- instead I voted up your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here the output will be two different integers,for two different `printf` statements . For the first `printf` statement the code prints `10`, then when this `printf` statement participate in some **assignment statement** , it is treated as the number of characters it is printing i.e. **2** here. Then it is added to `++b` i.e. `21` (**PRE-INCREMENTED**) . So the output is `23`(2 + 21) .
The whole output looks like this :

```
10
23
```

Answer (score 0):

printf returns the number of characters printed as an integer. So as you are printing 10 it will return 2.
So now

c=printf("%d",a)+ ++b; 
will become

c=2+ ++b;

since b with a value of 20 is pre-incremented this will become

c=2+21
Therefore c=23